# Why doesn't Linux use fibers instead of preemptive multitasking?

Tags: linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, kernel, coroutine

1. Can someone please explain what coroutines and [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29) are? What problem do they solve in comparison to
   the regular routines and multitasking mechanism.
2. Why does Linux use preemptive multitasking instead of cooperative
   multitasking?

Comment: You have a few interesting questions in here (what a coroutine is, what a fiber is, and when they would be useful over normal threads and subroutines), but I think you might want to post them as independent questions so that you can get a more direct answer.  Also, the question about why Linux uses preemptive multitasking is really interesting, but I think that it's hard to get a definitive answer.

Comment: This is two completely different questions in one.

Comment: If you consider that the prime advantage of preemptive mutitasking is to achieve high I/O performance by allowing I/O driver interrupts to rapidly make ready/running threads that are waiting for the I/O operations to complete, you should see that cooperative mutitasking is pretty err.. 'less than optimal' in a general-purpose OS.

Comment: Dunno - wasn't me.  maybe because you asked two questions in one?

Comment: Linux does not _necessarily_ use preemptive multitasking. `SCHED_FIFO` tasks use cooperative multitasking. However, preemptive multitasking is a good thing. It works well (much better than cooperative multitasking) for 99.9% of all programs that you would ever want to write.

Comment: At the kernel level (or at least at the task manager level of the kernel), trying to differentiate between preemptive multithreading doesn't make much sense. The kernel is like a Big Magician that tricks processes in user land into thinking that preemptive multi tasking is real. The CPU doesn't know about processes, the abstraction that is a thread or process is all done by the kernel. Any kernel level code that pretends that preemptive multi threading is real is just choosing to pretend to be ignorant of the magic tricks that it itself is performing, because the abstraction is useful.

Answer (score 9):

Coroutines, fibers and their ilk are thread-like execution contexts managed by programming language runtimes or libraries, rather than by the operating system, which regards them to be in one tread. They are of limited use; nobody in their right mind uses such hacks when real threads are available.

It's a simplification to say that Linux uses preemptive multitasking. Like early Unix, early Linux used cooperative multitasking for running kernel code. This means that processes can be preempted while executing user space, but not while executing kernel code. While running kernel code, a process is de-scheduled to run another process only if it sleeps, which happens by making some voluntary call to some blocking function that sleeps. This approach vastly simplifies the operating system internals, because a good many race conditions go away. At least, if there is only one processor. The task which is running kernel code only has to be worried about interrupts, and those can be briefly disabled whenever they are inconvenient.

With the introduction of support for multiple processors in the experimental Linux 1.3 kernel series in the middle 1990's, that picture begun to change. A nonpreemptive kernel doesn't support SMP very well because to maintain the guarantees of cooperative multi-tasking, a big lock has to be placed around the kernel which allows only one processor to enter at a time. In Linux, this was named BKL (big kernel lock).

Gradually, the BKL came not to be enforced around all entry into the kernel, and was displaced by finer-grained SMP locks. Once you have multiple processors running inside kernel space at the same time, there is a funny situation: real concurrency is going on, protected by locking mechanisms, and yet the kernel is still cooperative in that no task can lose the processor it is running on unless it sleeps.

At that point it makes sense to just allow preemption. And so that was worked into the kernel, in the form of the option `CONFIG_PREEMPT` which was experimental for many years and tended not to work consistently well across all architectures and in combination with SMP.

Why it is desirable for a kernel to be preemptible is simply that it allows for better real-time processing: shorter response times to events. While preemption is risky, most of the problems are solved by way of making SMP efficient, which tends to lower the bar for adoption of preemption: i.e. it's not a matter of "why, what for", but rather "why not".

Comment: *User-level* fibers can be quite useful, actually.  One huge advantage of them is far greater control over *when* something runs. If you're using fibers correctly, then when you set up a fiber, you can be assured that from your process's POV, (1) it will start exactly when you're ready to switch to it, and (2) it won't give up the CPU til it's ready (read: til stuff's back in a consistent state). That's precisely the type of control you give up with threads. You can try and scrounge back some of that control, but why give it up at all if you just want to be able to switch between tasks?

Comment: With all that said, it's probably a really good move by Linux to switch to preemptive multitasking in the kernel.  Particularly considering SMP got rid of the determinism anyway.

Comment: @cHao But Linux didn't do that. Linux provided the support and made it configurable via `CONFIG_PREEMPT`.  This means that the kernel developers do not feel that cooperative multitasking is something that should be abandonded.  For one thing, it simplifies bringup on a new architecture. You can get it working without `CONFIG_PREEMPT` first, and then debug issues with `CONFIG_PREEMPT`. Big advantage!

Answer (score 2):

Threads and fibers are both abstractions that enable multiple loci of execution (code paths).

Think of it as how a certain resource (CPU) is shared between these loci. The locus of execution that is given the CPU, is the one that executes.

With threads, the control of when the CPU is given to a thread, and taken away (i.e. when it executes and doesn't) is external. An external entity (the kernel scheduler) decides when a thread will get the CPU and how long. Time is usually a factor. The kernel shares the CPU among several threads, and if a thread doesn't give up the CPU voluntarily after a certain time, the kernel will take it away and give it to another thread, in a fair manner. The kernel may use various scheduling algorithms, that implement priority, responsiveness, and other goals, but the bottom line is that the CPU control lies in the hands of the kernel.

With coroutines (or fibers), a locus of execution keeps the CPU as long as it wants, and gives it up only voluntarily. At which point the kernel may assign the CPU to another locus of execution.

Note that giving up the CPU "voluntarily" can be explicit (by using some system call), or implicit (when it is built into other system calls like semaphore wait etc.). The general rule of thumb is that if a wait is likely to be involved in a system call, then an implicit schedule point is likely built into it.

It might be obvious by now that general purpose kernels like Linux don't use coroutines in a big way. This is because coroutines have too much independence in far as when they give up the CPU. A rogue fiber or a misbehaving one can hog the CPU for too long, and starve other loci of execution. Execution environments like Linux, like to have more control on how the CPU gets scheduled among all the loci of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Cooperative multitaskers are fatally crippled by being unable to provide low-latency I/O performance.

The ability of a preemptive multitasker to make I/O-waiting threads ready/running, preempting other running threads, whens a driver returns from an interrupt allows things like GUIs, browsers and the like to run responsively and video/music players, BitTorrent, YouTube,  etc. to actually work at all.

Cooperative tasking, like fibers and the so-called 'green threads' no doubt have their uses in niche areas, but they're next-to-useless in a general purpose OS, which is why Linux, Windows, (since W95, anyway), etc. etc. etc. all use a preemptive multithreading, (or multiprocessing, if you like), scheduler.

Comment: Much more generally, cooperative multitasking is not able to respond to a new event while processing an existing event (except in some limited way that happens at interrupt time, something that real-time applications do not have unless they are moved into the kernel). This is fine if the new event is less important, but not fine if the newly arriving event should be tended to ahead of the one in progress.

Comment: Cooperative tasking is not useless. Linux can be built without preemption and runs fine. Non-preemptive Linux ran crisply on 80386 and 80486 boxes, with multiple users logged in. (Of course, user space was always preemptive!). You can have responsibe browsing, bittorrent and youtube on a kernel without `CONFIG_PREEMPT`.